# pysqlite2: ProgrammingError - You must not use 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm currently persisting filenames in a sqlite database for my own purposes. Whenever I try to insert a file that has a special character (like é etc.), it throws the following error:

```
pysqlite2.dbapi2.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

When I do "switch my application over to Unicode strings" by wrapping the value sent to pysqlite with the unicode method like: `unicode(filename)`, it throws this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there something I can do to get rid of this? Modifying all of my files to conform isn't an option.

**UPDATE**
If I decode the text via `filename.decode("utf-8")`, I'm still getting the ProgrammingError above.

My actual code looks like this:

```
cursor.execute("select * from musiclibrary where absolutepath = ?;",
    [filename.decode("utf-8")])
```

What should my code here look like?

Comment: Looks like this code, after you updated the question, wasn't actually the code producing the error, right?

Comment: Right, it was similar code later on in the application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding of `filename` for conversion to Unicode, for example: `filename.decode('utf-8')`.  Just using `unicode(...)` picks the console encoding, which is often unreliable (and often `ascii`).

Comment: I tried doing that, but it seems that I'm still getting the errors mentioned above. I updated the post with what I'm doing now, so you can see what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I had some more bad conversion happening later on in my script that was throwing the same error :)

Answer (score 3):

You should pass as Unicode the arguments of your SQL statement.

Now, it all depends on *how* you obtain the filename list. Perhaps you're reading the filesystem using `os.listdir` or `os.walk`? If that is the case, there is a way to have directly the filenames as Unicode just by passing a Unicode argument to either of these functions:
Examples:

- `os.listdir(u'.')`
- `os.walk(u'.')`

Of course, you can substitute the `u'.'` directory with the actual directory whose contents you are reading. Just make sure it's a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass the unicode string directly:

```
cursor.execute("select * from musiclibrary where absolutepath = ?;",(u'namé',))
```

You will need to add the file encoding at the beginning of the script:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Comment: If I try that, it seems to be working. I'm iterating over around 3000 files, and it fails on a filename like: 02 - Neighborhood #2 (Laïka).mp3 . Is there a conversion technique that I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You figured this out already, but:

I don't think you could actually get that ProgrammingError exception from cursor.execute("select * from musiclibrary where absolutepath = ?;", [filename.decode("utf-8")]), as the question currently states.

Either the utf-8 decode would explode, or the cursor.execute call would be happy with the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change to this:

```
cursor.execute("select * from musiclibrary where absolutepath = ?;",
    [unicode(filename,'utf8')])
```

In your filename origin not encode with `utf8`, change `utf8` to your encoding.