# Storing long string of HTML in SQLite database causes unknown error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, unicode

I am storing some HTML in an SQLite3 database in Python.

When I go to insert some HTML into my SQL table I get an error that I don't understand what's wrong & more importantly how to fix the issue.

Error string:

> Exception General: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

The HTML string I am inserting into the table is pretty long (about 700 characters long).

Any idea whats wrong & how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838100/pysqlite2-programmingerror-you-must-not-use-8-bit-bytestrings

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838100/pysqlite2-programmingerror-you-must-not-use-8-bit-bytestrings), it looks like your issue is that you are attempting to insert HTML with characters in it that do not map to ASCII.  If you call `unicode(my_problematic_html)` you'll probably wind up with a `UnicodeEncodingError`.  In that case you'll want to `decode` your problematic string representation to unicode by calling:

```
my_unicoded_html = my_problematic_html.decode("utf-8")
```

and then writing `my_unicoded_html` to the database.

You'll want to read [*Unicode In Python Completely Demystified*](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

<sub>* Please note, your HTML *may* be encoded in some other codec (format? ... charset?) than `utf-8`.  `latin-1` is also a good guess if you are on Windows (or if the HTML might be from a Windows machine).</sub>