# list indices must be integer not str python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, compiler-errors

my code the error points to looks like this

```
for i in array1:
   cursor.execute("insert into Recipe values (?,?,?)",(array1[i], array2[i], array3[i]))
   db.commit()
```

the contents of the arrays are strings, so how would I put the arrays into the sqlite3 table?

Comment: Do you really have three arrays?  Why is the outer loop iterating over just one of them?

Comment: they are all the same size, I just wanted to count

Comment: Do you need the index value for anything, or just to iterate?  If it's just to iterate, consider using `zip` or `itertools.izip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over all three arrays together:

```
for row in zip(array1, array2, array3):
    cursor.execute("insert into Recipe values (?,?,?)", row)
db.commit()
```

Comment: this is perfect...almost, I just get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testread.py", line 21, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into Recipes values (?,?,?) ",row)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings. Any ideas?

Comment: @quantumdisaster: I presume you've read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838100/pysqlite2-programmingerror-you-must-not-use-8-bit-bytestrings and it hasn't helped?

Comment: right, it gives me an error about .decode not being a part of row

Comment: now I got that error fixed its bitching about only 1 binding being supplied when I called for 3 I changed the line of code to                cursor.execute("insert into Recipe values (?,?,?)",(u'row',))

Comment: These questions are a long way away from the one you asked! However, if I point out that `(u'row',)` is a tuple containing the unicode string "row", not the tuple containing elements from your three arrays, that should help you on your way...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
```

...but that's not quite as [idiomatic as it should be](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).